# What decides which part of the common XAML controls is accessible through UIAutomation

Tags: ui-automation, uwp-xaml, controltemplate, microsoft-ui-automation, winappdriver

I am trying to automate UI testing through `WinAppDriver` of a UWP app. The doc says that anything that is visible through the `inspect.exe` (i.e `UIAutomation`) could be controlled through `WinAppDriver`. This means the basic controls can be accessed through UIAutomation. And sometimes even content within these controls is accessible through UI Automation. Like the header for a `TextBlock` or `ToggleSwitch`, or the popup of a `ComboBox`.

Encouraged with this, I am modified the `ControlTemplate` of the common controls to make certain elements of the control visible through UIAutomation. See the example of [`ToggleSwitch`](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/404) (The default `ControlTemplate` does not expose the `OnContent` and `OffContent` properties of the `ToggleSwitch` as it is marked with `AutomationProperties.AutomationView = "Raw"`)

However, when I [attempted](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/512d6607-99fd-4363-9482-270a2f7da901/unable-to-access-xaml-elements-in-combobox-header-through-uiautomation?forum=windowsaccessibilityandautomation) to get the header of the `ComboBox`, I could not access it through `UIAutomation`.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Box">
    <ComboBox.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="This is a combobox" x:Name="Block" AutomationProperties.Name="TextBlock1" />
            <FontIcon VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Error"
                      FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                      Margin="2 0"
                      Glyph="&#xEB90;"
                      x:Name="FontIcon"
                      Foreground="DarkRed"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ComboBox.Header>
    <ComboBoxItem>Green</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Red</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

The `ControlTemplate` looks similar to other controls like `ToggleSwitch` and `TextBox`, but for whatever reason nothing defined in the `ControlTemplate` is made accessible to `UIAutomation`, except for the id and the popup list for `ComboBox`. So my question is what makes certain UI control expose their content (say `Header`) and some other not?